# Programmatically set left drawable in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

I have a textView in xml here.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkmark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dip"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

As you can see I set the DrawableLeft in xml.

I would like to change the drawable in code.

Is there anyway to go about doing this? Or setting the drawableLeft in code for the text view?

Answer (score 967, accepted):

You can use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

set 0 where you don't want images

Example for Drawable on the left:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can use [setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to respect RTL/LTR layouts.

---

Tip: Whenever you know any XML attribute but don't have clue about how to use it at runtime. just go to the description of that property in developer doc. There you will find **Related Methods** if it's supported at runtime . i.e. [For DrawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft)

Comment: So where do i set the drawable at in this method?

Comment: +1 Its working for setting android:drawableLeft for TextView programatically. Thanx mate

Comment: +1 for adding the tip.  that should be the very first thing devs are told when using the docs

Comment: @BrainCrash You're right, I mistook it with the newer method which has the same name.

Comment: How to use direct drawable? is there any other method? i have Bitmap object, how can i set like this. @BrainCrash

Comment: mTextViewExpand.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.mipmap.ic_add_48, 0);

Comment: Hello I was using this method to set the drawables, but I could not find its getter counter part. I had to check if the Compound textview has some drawable. How do I do that? Tried comparing `textview.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()[0]` with `mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable)`

Comment: if you want to use **Drawable** instead of drawable id you can go with `textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);`

Comment: what is that 0,0 means anyway?
What if we want to set the drawableRight as it's from xml programatically?

Answer (score 21):

### Using Kotlin:

You can create an extension function or just use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` directly.

```
fun TextView.leftDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int = 0) {
   this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(id, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

If you need to resize the drawable, you can use this extension function.

```
textView.leftDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon, R.dimen.icon_size)

fun TextView.leftDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int = 0, @DimenRes sizeRes: Int) {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id)
    val size = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(sizeRes)
    drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, size, size)
    this.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null)
}
```

To get really fancy, create a wrapper that allows size and/or color modification.

```
textView.leftDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon, colorRes = R.color.white)

fun TextView.leftDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int = 0, @DimenRes sizeRes: Int = 0, @ColorInt color: Int = 0, @ColorRes colorRes: Int = 0) {
    val drawable = drawable(id)
    if (sizeRes != 0) {
        val size = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(sizeRes)
        drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, size, size)
    }
    if (color != 0) {
        drawable?.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    } else if (colorRes != 0) {
        val colorInt = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)
        drawable?.setColorFilter(colorInt, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    }
    this.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null)
}
```

Answer (score 17):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) I see the method [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) can be used to do this.

Answer (score 8):

You can use any of the following methods for setting the Drawable on TextView:

1- [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

2- [setCompoundDrawables(Left_Drawable, Top_Drawable, Right_Drawable, Bottom_Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

And to get drawable from resources you can use:

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable_id);
```

Comment: No, setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int) is  API Levet 3 from your own link...

Answer (score 5):

A Kotlin extension + some padding around the drawable

```
fun TextView.addLeftDrawable(drawable: Int, padding: Int = 32) {
    val imgDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawable)
    compoundDrawablePadding = padding
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgDrawable, null, null, null)
}
```

Comment: Slightly different solution: `fun TextView.setDrawables(@DrawableRes start: Int = 0, @DrawableRes top: Int = 0, @DrawableRes end: Int = 0, @DrawableRes bottom: Int = 0) { setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(start, top, end, bottom) }`

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways of doing it either you can use XML or Java for it.
If it's static and requires no changes then you can initialize in XML.

```
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cloud_up"
    android:drawablePadding="5sp"
```

Now if you need to change the icons dynamically then you can do it by 
calling the icons based on the events

```
       textViewContext.setText("File Uploaded");
textViewContext.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.uploaded, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me to change the text view left/right drawable color

```
for (drawable in binding.tvBloodPressure.compoundDrawablesRelative) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(binding.tvBloodPressure.context, color),
                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
                )
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Java File for Activity :**
top,bottom,left,right are resource of icon.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);

// for example 
personalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.personal_info);
personalTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.personal, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this.

```
  txtUserName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        requireActivity().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.ic_my_account
        ), null, null, null
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can programmatically set the left drawable (also known as compound drawable) of a TextView using the setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds method. Here's an example in Java:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Assume you have a TextView with the id "textView"
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    // Set the left drawable programmatically
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable); // Replace with your drawable resource
    setLeftDrawable(textView, drawable);
}

private void setLeftDrawable(TextView textView, Drawable drawable) {
    // Set the left drawable with intrinsic bounds
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
}
}
```

Replace R.drawable.your_drawable with the actual resource ID of your drawable. This example assumes you have a TextView with the ID textView in your layout XML file.

Remember to handle cases where the drawable or TextView might be null, depending on your application logic.

Answer (score -8):

```
static private Drawable **scaleDrawable**(Drawable drawable, int width, int height) {

    int wi = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int hi = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int dimDiff = Math.abs(wi - width) - Math.abs(hi - height);
    float scale = (dimDiff > 0) ? width / (float)wi : height /
            (float)hi;
    Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, (int)(scale * wi), (int)(scale * hi));
    drawable.setBounds(bounds);
    return drawable;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. TextView related answer is expected.