# How to change an icon of the TextView programmatically?

Tags: android, textview

In the xml you can set a drawable to the left, right, bottom or top of the text in TextView. Is there a way to set / change this drawable through a code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically set left drawable in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931900/programmatically-set-left-drawable-in-a-textview)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
  R.drawable.icon, //left
  0, //top
  0, //right
  0);//bottom
```

Comment: good answer, but my app must support right to left languages, so i need use start instead of left, could you help me please.

Comment: @MoHaKa use setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()