# Move text right to leave space for a button in EditText. Possible?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textview, android-edittext

Here's something similar to what I'm trying to achieve (see image). I have the delete button (on the right) working, so I know how to add the buttons. But how can I shift the text to leave room for the button on the left?

[image]

Comment: please be a little more clear with your question and post your xml layout file. we can help you if we know which layout, views etc you are using.

Comment: You can do this incredibly simply with `drawableLeft`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931900/setting-drawableleft-in-a-textview-problem ; There is an XML example in the question, and one using Java in the answer.

Comment: @Eric That would be helpful if only some static images were to be displayed. But I presume that he needs to detect click on those images which I dont think is possible by using left and right drawables. To handle drawables click one would need a custom EditText as given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554377/handling-click-events-on-a-drawable-within-an-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of ImageViews you can use Buttons or any other View. Also adjust the margins and paddings according to your need.

Comment: Thanks, @Antrromet. PaddingLeft=x was just what I needed.