# how to setImage at right side Textview Programatically

Tags: android, textview

i can set image textview rightside using xml attribute like

```
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtarrow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="VideoClick"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:textColor="#feb4e7" >
                </TextView>
```

i want to set

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
```

programatically
like

```
txtarrow1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_blue);
```

but this one is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting DrawableLeft in a TextView problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931900/setting-drawableleft-in-a-textview-problem)

Comment: add this "android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher" line in your xml textview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use Google to find the Android java docs of TextView.
They have a huge table showing every attribute's its programatical option.

```
android:drawableRight   (@compile time)
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)    (@runtime)
```

The drawable to be drawn to the right of the text.

Answer (score 4):

Here You want to use

## Adding image on specific direction in Text View pro-grammatically

There are 2 method :

1> **Through Image Drawable**

ex:

```
    Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.dogy );
    txtarrow1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 
    img,// left 
    null,//top 
    null,// right 
    null//bottom);
```

Remember this method is most use-full in image store in one view (Text View , Button)

2> **Through Image Id**

```
        txtarrow1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 
        R.drawable.ic_doggy,// left 
        0,//top 
        0,// right 
        0//bottom);
```

Most probably these method use in different images display in multiple view like **(GridView)**

Must remember difference between these two when **Drawable** can't show image set **null** & in **ID**  set **0** (zero)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SpannableString`..

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("text");
text.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.arrow_blue), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
txtarrow1.setText(text);
```