# Android: How to set drawable visible

Tags: android, textview, drawable

This is my code :

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/error_image"
                android:textColor="#aa0000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

i have a drawable that i want to set it invisible and then when error occurred drawable appears.How can i do it?

Comment: use  android:visibility="invisible" in xml file. use Textview.setvisibility=view.visible in java class

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence). you can use set error for textview

Comment: @ravneet: I know it but i think that should do it in another way but it's worked. thank you.

Comment: @ravneet : how can i set drawable near the text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

set 0 if you want to invisible image

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

For reference

[Programmatically set left drawable in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931900/setting-drawableleft-in-a-textview-problem)

Comment: i do this in another way, but there is space between image and text, how can i do this? i want reduce this space.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the reference by invoke `TextView.getCompoundDrawables()` method, then set the right drawable's alpha to `0` (invisible) or `255` (visible).

Answer (score 0):

*-> If you want to Invisible 'android:drawableEndicon' then set*

note :- Email is the findViewById of view like edittext

> Email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0);

*-> If you want to visible 'android:drawableEndicon' then set*

> Email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);