# Is it possible to insert/paste image on a custom EditText?

Tags: android, textview

I wanted to create a custom text view. A little bit advance just as the text editor found here in StackOverflow, I can insert text and even images. I wanted to name this as WordView and create this as a library so I can reuse this across multiple projects.

Unfortunately I am not so sure if the base class allows this. I need a way to insert/paste images directly in the EditText. I am planning to write a custom View, although it seems laborious, I am not quite certain if this is possible at all and if I am going into the right track.

Have anyone tried similar before?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android Documentation for a TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) You can have a drawable object inside the TextView in the following ways

1. [DrawableBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom)
2. [DrawableEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableEnd)
3. [DrawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft)
4. [DrawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight)
5. [DrawableStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableStart)
6. [DrawableTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop)

There are other methods you can use, check out:
 1. [Programmatically set left drawable in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931900/setting-drawableleft-in-a-textview-problem) 
 2. [How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)
 3. http://androidsbs.blogspot.co.za/2013/12/androiddrawableleft-set-drawable-to.html

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly implement this [using HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview). I'm not sure about the paste functionality but generally it might work.

Comment: Wow this is a very useful link. I've been looking for this kind of concept for ages. I have to make assessment first on this one. Thanks!